# Randomly selecting a function

Tags: javascript

I am creating just a little test game type thing, and for part of it, I need a function to be randomly selected.

I have 2 altogether, and I just need to create maybe a 'random generator' somehow, which I can call, and it runs one of the 2 functions.

```
function function1() {
  ........code.........
}

function function2() {
  ........code.........
}

function generator() {
...random function selector...
}
```

Maybe something like that ^

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (Math.random() < 0.5) func1(); else func2();`

Comment: So where are you stuck? What have you tried that didn't work? You can't just dump an assignment here and expect somebody to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.

```
var myFuncArr = ["function1","function2"];
function generator(){
  window[myFuncArr[Math.random() * (myFuncArr.length - 0) + 0]]();
}
```

Comment: downvoter, care to elaborate?

Comment: there is no need of array.. for simple random switching.. check cookie monster's comment.

Comment: The array is the name of functions. What is wrong in it?

Comment: yeah no wrong in it.. but how OP will put the random number between 0 and 1? (_took back -1_)

Comment: @Mr_Green, I'm coming on it. Wait

Comment: please you are making me to downvote you again by using eval. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green, all fine now.

Comment: Why the `- 0) + 0`? The subtraction and addition doesn't change the value. And why put strings in an Array? What if they're not global variables? It would seem better to put the functions in the Array.

Comment: @cookiemonster I like your one line answer which you posted as comment. I don't know why Amit is doing so many things here which are not necessary.

Comment: @Mr_Green: Thanks. I do like the Array idea if there could be more functions, but not crazy about the string names. I think with the math he may have been thinking of integer division, though that wouldn't be applicable in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has an [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function that evaluates a string and executes it as code:

```
function generator(){
  min = 1;
  max = 5; 
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  param = "myParam";
  eval("function"+random+"('"+param+"')");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you expecting like this

```
function method1(){
    document.getElementById("sampleDiv").style.color = "red";
}

function method2(){
    document.getElementById("sampleDiv").style.color = "yellow";
}


function method3(){
    document.getElementById("sampleDiv").style.color = "orange";
}

function generator(id) {
    eval("method"+id+"()")
}

function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
}

setInterval(function(){generator(randomIntFromInterval(1,3))},3000);
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hcmY9/3/